# Is it possible to add a sequence in oracle available to all users automatically?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to add a sequence that's publicly available to all users automatically in an Oracle database. I don't want to have to worry about granting permissions to every new user every time they're added.

The reason for the sequence is to ensure a unique value for something written across all schemas.

Is it possible to make a schema object publicly available to all users (and all future users)?

Comment: You can grant select to `PUBLIC`, but this is rarely done. Explicit, per user permissions are the industry standard best practice.

Comment: @pmdba I'm not sure what you mean by PUBLIC. I don't think that schema exists in Oracle

Comment: `PUBLIC` is not a schema. When you run a grant like `GRANT EXECUTE ON ... TO PUBLIC`, it will grant all schemas (current and future) that privilege

Comment: looks like granting to public works. Thanks!